# Cocos Creator JavaScript the callback function of cc.resources.load not work

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

I used cc.resources.load() and modify the value of parameter in properties, but it doesn't work when I read the value of parameter out of callback function. Is there anybody who can help me, thanks!!!!The language is JavaScript.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the second `console.log` is executed right after `resources.load` is called, but the first log is asynchronous when loaded. It may take 0.1s, 1s, or more.
The correct program order is:

```
1. this.voicePool = []
2. cc.resources.load
3. console.log(this.test.duration);(the second one in your screenshot)
4.(a few moment later) function(err,assets){
    self.test = assets
}
```